# What is the equivalent of OracleBulkCopy(string connectionString) for Oracle.ManagedDataAccess?

Tags: c#, oracle

I have some trouble with C# and Oracle. I need to find the equivalent of this line of code using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess :

```cs
using (Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleBulkCopy bulkcopy = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleBulkCopy(this.connectionString)) 
{
        bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = TargetTable;
        bulkcopy.WriteToServer(UploadDataReader);
}
```

*connectionString* is a String, *TargetTable* is a string defining the name of an Oracle Table and *UploadDataReader* is a DataReader which defines the data you want to put in the target table.

For some reasons I prefer to use ManagedDataAccess instead of DataAccess.
Would you know a way to make a bulkcopy from a string connection using only "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess"?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Bull copyis not supported by the managed driver, you find this also in the documentation.

Comment: Yes I kknow about it. Yet I think there might be an alternative for my example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be back again:

> ODP.NET Core and managed ODP.NET now support bulk copy, which allows fast data  transfer between .NET and Oracle databases equivalent to a direct path load.  ODP.NET Core and managed ODP.NET support the same bulk copy APIs as unmanaged ODP.NET, which makes porting existing apps easier. These APIs are documented in the latest ODP.NET Developer’s Guide.

Found on [Alex Keh's blog](https://medium.com/@alex.keh/announcing-odp-net-19-10-release-new-net-5-and-bulk-copy-support-be6f395155c9)